# C# Visual Studio Mac what happens when you press the play button for an iOS app?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, jenkins, visual-studio-mac

I am trying to create a build for Jenkins that builds a csproj for an iOS app and then I run tests using the .app file generated from the build. After looking into it further I have isolated the problem to this specific portion of my build.

In my Jenkins build I have built the csproj successfully using msbuild and then I run the tests. The build generates an .app file but that file does not install on an iPhoneSimulator, producing this error:

```
Original error: simctl error running 'install': An error was encountered processing the command (domain=IXUserPresentableErrorDomain, code=2):
  This app was unable to be installed.
```

On the other hand, opening the project in Visual Studio Mac, building, and then pressing the play button the app is successfully installed on an iPhone Simulator. Running the tests after that all work as well.

So what build step am I missing after I build the csproj that actually deploys a correct .app file to be installed?

Specific steps and information:

- I restore and build all dependent projects
- I build using the correct configuration and platform, i.e. Release|iPhoneSimulator
- The app is correctly signed

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Run `xcrun simctl install {sim device that you are installing to} /path/to/your/app/{your app name}.app`, do you get the same error? Any more details?

Comment: @SushiHangover running that I get an error (domain=IXUserPresentableErrorDomain, code=2): This app was unable to be installed.

Comment: Is the simulator device in booted state?

Comment: @SushiHangover yes, the command usually show a different error if the simulator isn't booted. The main problem is why the .app file created from the terminal build can't be installed while the .app file created when pressing the play button can be installed.